# git branch with migrations run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I checked out a branch in git to experiment with developing a feature that involved making three migrations, which I have run. Preserving the very small amount of data in the db is not important. How do I handle this when merging the branch back into master? Should I rollback the migrations before merging, and then run them again after merged (as seemed to be suggested by one SO answer), or do I leave it as is and just commit everything to the branch and then merge it without rolling anything back. Another SO answer suggested removing the db from the gitignore file, but it wasn't clear if that was only necessary in situations where preserving data might be important.

```
# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not track your `*.sqlite3` development files in git.

You should

1. Merge `master` into your branch
2. Make sure all is well
3. Checkout `master`
4. Merge the branch back into `master`
5. Continue development

The merge will pull in your migrations from the branch. You could rollback before the merge, do the merge, and then migrate, but there's no need; the resulting schema at the end will be identical.

---

In situations where a rollback/migration would be necessary, it's likely your migrations between `master` and the branch conflict with one another somehow. This is something you'd fix in step #2 above when you're "Making sure all is well".

As a general rule, you should be able to take a completely blank database, run `rake db:migrate` and end up with an up-to-date database structure without anything failing. This is why step #2 above is important, to ensure you're not merging a breaking/conflicting migration back into `master`.

As for situations where you are risking losing data in development, this is what fixtures are for. You can use Rails seeding functionality, or a gem like [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).